# Crear un arreglo 4x4 para calcular el promedio y la desviación standard

Tags: java, array

Necesito crear un arreglo con los siguientes números
y calcular:

Por renglon: El promedio y la desviación standard

El promedio y la desviacion standard de todo el arreglo

> {3,8,7,6} {7,5,7,4} {3,2,1,0} {9,6,4,8}

Esto es lo que llevo pero no funciona en la parte de desviacion y al parecer solo calucula de todo el arreglo

```
public class arreglo4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int data[][] = { { 3, 8, 7, 6 }, { 7, 5, 7, 4 }, { 3, 2, 1, 0 }, { 9, 6, 4, 8 } };

        // acumulador
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + data.length;
        }

        // desplegar
        for (int ren = 0; ren < data.length; ren++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < data[ren].length; col++) {
                System.out.println(data[col][ren] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        // promedio

        double mean = sum / data.length;
        System.out.println("promedio " + mean);

        // Desviacion

        double sum1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum1 = sum1 + ((data[i]-mean) * (data[i]-mean));
        }
        double s=Math.sqrt(sum1/(data.length-1));
        System.out.println("La desviacion es " +s);
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor comparte que has intentado para poder ayudarte, pues no me parece que estés planteando que tengas algún problema en específico con lo que pusiste

Answer (score 0):

Así se declara un arreglo multidimensional:

```
int matriz[][] = new int[4][4];
```

Puedes declararlo e inicializarlo a la vez de la siguiente manera:

```
int matriz[][] = {{3,8,7,6}, {7,5,7,4}, {3,2,1,0}, {9,6,4,8}}
```

Debes publicar como se calcula lo que necesitas y el código de lo cómo lo has intentado hacer.

Comment: La pregunta indica que ya tiene esto, pero necesita El promedio y la desviación standard.

Comment: Creo no viste la pregunta original...

Comment: En el titulo no lo indicaba, ero en el cuerpo de la pregunta si menciona que requiere promedio y la desviación standard de los elementos almacenados en el array.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quiere sacar la media de cada una de las sub-arrays y luego hacer la media de todas estas.
Para crear array multidimensionales (matrices), debes escribir:

```
int matriz[][] = new int [4][4]
//tambien crearemos unas variables para guardar las medias
int mediaTotal = 0;
int subMedia = 0;
```

Para poder moverte por ellas debes crear un doble `for` (nested for):

```
for(i=0;i<matriz.lenght;i++){
   for(j=0;j<matriz.lenght;i++){
//aqui harias la media de cada sub-array
submedia += matriz[i][j];
}
System.out.println("media de sub-array "+i+": "+subMedia)
mediaTotal += submedia/2;
} 
System.out.println("media total de todos los arrays: "+mediaTotal);
```

En cuanto a las desviaciones...no se a que te refieres, espero haberte ayudado. Un upvote se agradece :P

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema puedes usar los streams de java 8 y un collector para calcular la  [desviación standard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125409/computing-the-standard-deviation-of-a-number-array-in-java)

```
 int data[][] = { { 3, 8, 7, 6 }, { 7, 5, 7, 4 }, { 3, 2, 1, 0 }, { 9, 6, 4, 8 } };
    Arrays.stream(data).mapToDouble(x ->  Arrays.stream(x).
            average().
            orElse(0) ).
            forEach(s -> System.out.println("promedio "+s));

    double average = Arrays.stream(data).
            flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).
            average().orElse(0);
    System.out.println("promedio total "+average);

    Arrays.stream(data).mapToDouble(x ->  Arrays.stream(x).
            mapToDouble((int s) -> 1.0 * s).
            boxed().
            collect(DoubleStatistics.collector())).
            forEach(s -> System.out.println("desviacion estandar "+s));

    double r = Arrays.stream(data).
                    flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).
                    mapToDouble((int s) -> 1.0 * s).
                    boxed().
                    collect(DoubleStatistics.collector());

    System.out.println("desviacion estandar total "+r);
```

y el código del collector

```
public class DoubleStatistics extends DoubleSummaryStatistics {

    private double sumOfSquare = 0.0d;
    private double sumOfSquareCompensation; // Low order bits of sum
    private double simpleSumOfSquare; // Used to compute right sum for
    // non-finite inputs

    @Override
    public void accept(double value) {
        super.accept(value);
        double squareValue = value * value;
        simpleSumOfSquare += squareValue;
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(squareValue);
    }

    public DoubleStatistics combine(DoubleStatistics other) {
        super.combine(other);
        simpleSumOfSquare += other.simpleSumOfSquare;
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(other.sumOfSquare);
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(other.sumOfSquareCompensation);
        return this;
    }

    private void sumOfSquareWithCompensation(double value) {
        double tmp = value - sumOfSquareCompensation;
        double velvel = sumOfSquare + tmp; // Little wolf of rounding error
        sumOfSquareCompensation = (velvel - sumOfSquare) - tmp;
        sumOfSquare = velvel;
    }

    public double getSumOfSquare() {
        double tmp = sumOfSquare + sumOfSquareCompensation;
        if (Double.isNaN(tmp) && Double.isInfinite(simpleSumOfSquare)) {
            return simpleSumOfSquare;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public final double getStandardDeviation() {
        long count = getCount();
        double sumOfSquare = getSumOfSquare();
        double average = getAverage();
        return count > 0 ? Math.sqrt((sumOfSquare - count * Math.pow(average, 2)) / (count - 1)) : 0.0d;
    }

    public static Collector<Double, DoubleStatistics, Double> collector() {
    return Collector.of(DoubleStatistics::new,
            DoubleStatistics::accept, DoubleStatistics::combine, DoubleStatistics::getStandardDeviation);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummmm me preocupa un poco esta línea:

```
    // acumulador
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + data.length;
    }
```

Veo que sum acumulará los valores de todo el arreglo, pero...

```
        sum = sum + data.length;
```

Estas siempre agregando a la variable sum el tamaño del arreglo, y como resultado la variable sum siempre va a tener el valor 16, cosa que es incorrecta.

La forma correcta es iterando atravez de cada uno de los valores de los arreglos que están dentro de nuestro arreglo principal de esta manera:

```
    // acumulador
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){

            sum += data[i][j];

        }
    }
```

Supongo que eso arreglaria el problema tratándose del arreglo entero.

En caso de hacer esto mismo pero con un subarreglo solo debes iterar atravez del subelemento x que necesites y usar el length de ese subarreglo para las operaciones siguientes:

```
    // acumulador
    double sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < data[2].length; j++){

          sum += data[2][j];

     }
```

Por ejemplo solo haciendo los cálculos para el subarreglo en la posición 2 harias algo como eso.

El resto del código considero que está bien, y que si por alguna razón te da error a lo mejor no se trata de lo que llevas si no alguna cosa que agregaste mal o que se te olvidó modificar o arreglar.